# How to access a value in a plist, given its key

Tags: plists

I have a list of key-value pairs that is assigned to a variable.

```
(setq m-point '(:beg 2811 :end 3018 :op "(" :cl ")" :prefix "" :suffix ""))
```

How do I access the values of `:beg` and `:end` within it?

---

## Context

I wrote a function that makes use of `sp-forward-sexp` and `sp-backward-sexp` of `smartparens-mode` to get the positions of a pair of custom parenthesis.

```
   (defun paren-position ()
      "Returns a list of positions where parenthesis has been sitting."
      (interactive)
      (let ((m-point ;; find point with matching parenthesis with `(scan-sexps)`. 
         (list
          (ignore-errors (sp-backward-sexp)
          (ignore-errors (sp-forward-sexp))))))
    (flatten (remove nil m-point))))
```

`(:beg 2811 :end 3018 :op "(" :cl ")" :prefix "" :suffix ""))` is the value returned when the function is called.

This is the first time I am working with such a list with only key-value pairs (somewhat like a Python dictionary), and I don't quite know how to go about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a list of key-value pairs that is assigned to a variable.
>
> ```
> (setq m-point '(:beg 2811 :end 3018 :op "(" :cl ")" :prefix "" :suffix ""))
> ```

This is known as a *property list* or *plist*.

> How do I access the values of `:beg` and `:end` within it?

```
(plist-get m-point :beg)
=> 2811
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Property Lists` for more information.

Comment: For any future readers, the *original* title of the question did not use the term "plist" -- hence my identifying it as such here in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the built-in `plist-get` function, you can also do this Common Lisp style using the `getf` function from the built-in [`cl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/) package.

```el
(require 'cl)
(getf '(:a 1 :b 2) :a)
;; => 1
```

One benefit is that you can then change the value associated with a key using `setf`:

```el
(defvar l (list :a 1))
(setf (getf l :a) 2)
l
;; => (:a 2)
```

Something similar can be achieved in vanilla Elisp using `plist-put`:

```el
(setq l (plist-put l :a 3))
l
;; => (:a 3)
```